# class with in nested list class add record in windows phone 8 c# class

Tags: c#

I have created two classes; I want to add one employee list to my department class. I tried to add it using object.AddRange(), but it threw a null exception. I've attached the screenshot. Please give me the solution.

```
public class department
{
public List<Employee> employee { get; set; }
public Int64 dptid { get; set; }
public string dptname { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{  
public empid{get; set;}
public empname{get; set;}
}

department objdept= new department();
Employee objemp;

foreach(var d in deptDetail){
objdept.dptid=d.dptid;
objdept.dptname=d.dptname;    
    foreach(var e in empdetail)
    {
    objemp=new Employee;
    objemp=e.empid;
    objemplist.add(objemp)
    }

objdept.employee.AddRange(objemplist)     //// this line show null exception 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The department class has a "employee" property. When you instantiate the object (by using new), this property is set to null (since that is the default for all reference types).

You need to instantiate the list before adding to it:

```
department objdept= new department();
Employee objemp;

foreach(var d in deptDetail){
objdept.dptid=d.dptid;
objdept.dptname=d.dptname;    
    foreach(var e in empdetail)
    {
    objemp=new Employee;
    objemp=e.empid;
    objemplist.add(objemp)
    }

objdept.employee = new List<Employee>();
objdept.employee.AddRange(objemplist)     //// this line show null exception
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i got solution if we want add list in nested class use = operator.

Example:
 public class department
        {
            public List<Employee> employee { get; set; }
            public Int64 dptID { get; set; }
            public string dptName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public int empid { get; set; }
            public string empName { get; set; }
        }
objdpt.dptid=1;
objdpt.dptName="Name";
objdpt.employee=objemp;
thats enough. i i told this i like to share this result. because u spent time for me thank a lot.

Comment: Ummm... ok. Glad you got it figured out! Pretty sure you still need to instantiate the list before the exception will go away though...

Comment: Thanks, i need another one help i have used 1.longlist selector with in pivot control as dynamic. if i change pivot item it load next 10 images as grid. when i go to next pivot item it shows  "System.OutOfMemoryException"

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the pivot control, but if you are getting an OutOfMemoryException you are probably doing some sort of out of control recursion. When you feel the question has been answered, remember to mark the most helpful answer as "accepted". I'm curious to know if my answer was correct, or was there a separate problem? It was kind of hard to understand what was different about the code in your comment.